# selecting the bins for extremely skewed data

Tags: data-visualization, descriptive-statistics, skewness, power-law, binning

I have a data that exhibits nearly a power law distribution, and I want to know a good binning technique to summarize the statistics.

For example consider the following data:
$$
\begin{array}{rr}
\textbf{Object} & \textbf{Count}\\
A & 82952\\
B & 8832\\
C & 1801\\
D & 555\\
E & 231\\
F & 123\\
G & 60\\
H & 43\\
I & 28\\
J & 20\\
K & 8\\
L & 13\\
M & 4\\
N & 4\\
O & 4\\
P & 3
\end{array}
$$

The count is the number of times "Object X" appears. As you can see from "Object J" and onwards, the frequencies of "Object K–P" are too low. So I want to combine "Object K-P" into one bin. The regular techniques like "equal width" and "equal frequency" binning do not work. I can manually write a program to do this, but is there any statistical discretization technique that can effectively bin such patterns?

Comment: What about defining the widths of bins logarithmically?

Comment: The binning you describe does not appear consistent with making mere summaries.  Why do you really want to make these bins?

Comment: The reason for making these bins requires a lengthy explanation. In short, the objects K-P for instance is just too less (ie the frequency) when compared to other objects. Treating them as individual objects is trivial. So for my analysis I found that it is better to combine such objects together. May be H-K can be combined together into one bin too. So what binning technique to use (if any) is the question.

Comment: @Alexis Yes that is definitely a good option. Thanks